# Remove CommandBar created by an Addin in Word 2003

Tags: ms-office, add-in, office-interop, office-2003

I have installed a Word 2003 Add-in, then uninstalled it, but unfortunately I still seeing the menu created by the Add-in in the Word menu bar.

I tried Tools -> Customize, and there I can remove the submenus, but not the main one.

Do you know how to remove it permanently?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following links

[Microsoft Word Add-ins - Install, Uninstall and Removal](http://www.msoffice-tutorial-training.com/word-add-in.html)

[Load or unload add-in programs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/load-or-unload-add-in-programs-HP005203732.aspx)